# How to paste a code to terminal and execute it line by line? (it has sudo)

Tags: command-line

**As an example:**

When I paste to terminal the following code:

```
wclean;
sudo bash;
wmake;
```

It asks for password for `sudo bash`, then I have to type it (*no problem*). But it doesn't keep going. It stops before `wmake`.

**Then**

How to paste *an* entire *custom* code to terminal and execute it line by line?
I want a simple solution because these codes I paste are from internet, books, tutorials, ...

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't keep going? Because it definitely should. It may seem so because running `sudo bash` spawns a new shell and that `wmake` is not run in that shell. Using `exit` command closes current shell session and you should be able to see if it was run

Comment: Actually it makes no sense here to run `sudo bash` as that only launches a root shell, but you seem to do nothing with it

Comment: It was an example. But could I just type `wclean wmake`? @ByteCommander . (I took it from internet)

Comment: @Vitor If you run `wclean wmake`, Bash will run the command `wclean` and pass it the string `wmake` as first argument. If you want to run them both as separate commands but on the same line, you must separate them by either `;` (first command runs, then second command runs), `&&` (first command runs, then second command runs only if first command was successful), `||` (first command runs, then second command runs only if first command exited with an error) or `&` (first command starts in background, second command starts immediately in parallel).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pasting multiple commands at once may lead to problems if one of them waits for terminal input. In this case the rest of the paste will be taken as input for that command and not as separate command to be run afterwards. The most common example is probably the `sudo` password prompt.

However, Bash is capable of opening a text editor to enter commands, by default it is `nano`. You start the command editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. The editor launches and everything you typed into the current command line so far will also appear there and can be edited. If the command line was empty though, the editor will be empty as well.

In the editor you can now easily paste or type multiple commands, simply put one command per line and Bash will execute them one by one. You can also put a whole script in there, it does not matter. The content you write gets internally saved as temporary file and executed almost like a Bash script. The only difference here is that if you have multiple commands, Bash will first print the command itself before executing it.

If you're done with editing and want to submit your list of commands, simply exit the editor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for `nano`). It will ask you whether to save the changes and you answer "<kbd>Y</kbd>es" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the proposed temporary file name. Bash will then start to execute all the commands one after the other.

Comment: Perfect! Just mention in your answer that your file should be saved when exiting (it may be obvious to you, but I discover it by trial and error)

Comment: @Vitor Thanks for your feedback, I improved my answer a bit. Better now?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the answer is to change the commands you're using. You are trying to start a bash shell as root in order to run a command. The clean way of doing this is to just run `sudo command`. So, all you need is to copy paste the following directly into your terminal:

```
wclean
sudo wmake
```

You don't need to first run `sudo bash` and *then* `wmake`, run `wmake` with `sudo` directly. You also don't need the `;` at the end of each command. The `;` is only needed if you are running two commands on the same line (e.g. `comm1; comm2`).

Comment: It was only an example. I understand that in this case we can just change the order.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter as super user, all the command you run will be granted with super user privileges, so no password will be asked.

Just type `sudo su` on the terminal prompt before pasting your commands. The prompt must have been changed from $ to #.

Comment: This violates the principle of least privileges. Commands always should be run with the lowest privileges possible, that means not to run anything as root unless it's really necessary. Opening a root shell is something you should avoid as well.

Comment: Also, please don't use `sudo su`. [It's inelegant and not needed](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218169/22222). Use `sudo -i` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, copy that and paste in a file, and then execute the file,
For Example:

```
nano test.sh
Ctrl+Shift+V [to paste the code]
Ctrl+O [Save it]
Ctrl+X [Exit]
chmod 755 test.sh
./test.sh
```

Cheers

Comment: No need for a temporary file, Bash has such a command editor feature built in. See my answer for details. But other than that, you could also save one step by running `bash test.sh` instead of `chmod 755 test.sh ; ./test.sh`. And `chmod +x test.sh` would also be easier.

Comment: Thanks for  that info , yeah `sh test.h` would even save two letters, :P . Umm using 755 is easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

As @jiipeezz commented, there's nothing wrong with not continue after `sudo bash`, because with this command you open a new shell. In fact, terminating the shell ( with `exit` ) the the next command is executed. If you want to run the command `wmake` as superuser, then you have to pass the command as argument to shell, with `sudo bash -c 'wmake'`.
Try:

```
wclean;
sudo bash -c 'wmake';
```

But I do not think it makes sense to run a single command on a new shell, instead it uses sudo to run the command directly.

Answer (score -1):

You could change the semicolons(;) with '&&' without the quotes, in your case for example:

```
wclean &&
sudo bash &&
wmake
```

BTW no '&&' at the end.

Have a nice day

Comment: And what advantage would this have over the OP's initial approach with semicolons? `&&` only means that the next command only gets executed if the previous one ran successfully without error (exit code 0). This does not help here.

Comment: This way the command after command with sudo is executed. With the semicolons it does not. (at least not when I try).

Comment: No, with `;` the last command will get executed anyway, but with `&&` it will get executed only if the previous command exited successfully.